# C# skips readlines

Tags: c#, while-loop

I've got a While loop that reads a file. The problem is that it reads 1 line, then skips one, read, skip, and so on.
I can't figure out what causes it to skip. If somebody could tell me that'' be awesome (:

```
StreamReader sentencesFile = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Jeroen\Desktop\School\C#\opwegmetcsharp\answersSen.txt");
string line;

while ((line = sentencesFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string SentenceFileString = sentencesFile.ReadLine();
    string keyWords = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
    string sentence = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
    string testOutput= keyWords + sentence;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are reading the line inside the `while` loop's condition already. You don't need to read it again as the first statement in the loop.

```
while ((line = sentencesFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string SentenceFileString = line;  // can be removed
    string keyWords = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
    string sentence = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
    string testOutput = keyWords + sentence;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Forgot to delete that line and didn't notice it didn't do anything else than ruining the code :/ Whoops

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
while ((line = sentencesFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string SentenceFileString = sentencesFile.ReadLine();
```

when you ask for the line !=null you are already reading one line,
this will skip again with the

```
string SentenceFileString = sentencesFile.ReadLine();
```

---

## soution:

comment out that 2nd line (you are not even using the variable `SentenceFileString`)and keep working with the while

```
while ((line = sentencesFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    
    string keyWords = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '));
    string sentence = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
    string testOutput= keyWords + sentence;
}
```